# Apache + SuExec + php-fpm - how to set them up?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-fcgid, php-fpm, suexec, suphp

I wonder if there is a good guide on how to setup Apache + SuExec + php-fpm? I have a server which I am going to use several separate website. So, I need php to be run as site-owner user. As I can see, php-fpm is a little different from php-fcgi. Is there a need in mod_fcgid from Apache in this case? How to set this all up?

For now my site is running Apache + mod_suphp + php-cgi, so... it's good, but a little slow. I want to preserve security and gain an ability to use APC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[PHP-FPM](http://php-fpm.org/) is a patch for PHP to provide some advanced process management features which are useful when used in its FastCGI variant. On a side note, PHP 5.4 will probably include PHP-FPM out of the box ([according to Antony Dovgal](http://groups.google.com/group/highload-php-en/msg/29a9a35bca58da55)).

Since [mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) doesn't support externally spawned FastCGI servers, you need to use [mod_fastcgi](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html) or [mod_proxy_fcgi](http://mproxyfcgi.sourceforge.net/).

Google found this two-part tutorial ([Part 1](http://learnix.net/fastasscgi-part1/), [Part 2](http://learnix.net/fastasscgi-part2/)) which describes the configuration of Apache httpd, suEXEC, mod_fastcgi, PHP-FPM and APC. I haven't tried the tutorial but it should give you an idea of how to configure it.

Comment: -1 ... The links provided for the *alleged* two-part tutorial return 404.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial explain how to set up PHP-FPM (bundle with PHP 5.3.3) with Apache2 :

http://blog.myprod.net/2010/08/14/apache2-suexec-fastcgi-php-5-3-3-fpm-cache-opcode-apc/

Comment: ...in French...